# Update site (eclipse-repository) does not contain new plugin of patch feature

Tags: tycho

We use patch feature for patching installation with new versions of
plugins. This is the first time when the feature contains a new plugin
that did not exist in the previous version of the (full) feature.

To take example, consider that Feature F in version 1.0 contains two
plugins P1 and P2, and in version 1.1 it contains three -- P1, P2 and
P3. We use the id F.patch_1_1 for the 1.1 patch feature for F. So:

- F:1.0 contains P1:1.0, P2:1.0
- F:1.1 contains P1:1.1, P2:1.1, P3:1.1
- F.patch_1_1:1.1 contains P1:1.1, P2:1.1, P3:1.1

In the eclipse-feature build, the generated target/feature.xml lists
all three plugins, and their versions have been changed from
1.1.qualifier to 1.1.nnn1, where n1 is the timestamp.

In the eclipse-repository build, the generated feature jar
(target/repository/F.patch_1_1.1.1.n2.jar --- n2 being a later
timestamp than n1) contains the identical feature.xml. But actual
plugin jar is missing from target/repository/plugins directory. This
is the only plugin missing, all the others are present.

During the update-site build, the following a warning is logged from
Mirror tool:
[WARNING] Mirror tool: "Problems resolving provisioning plan.":
["Unable to satisfy dependency from F.patch_1_1.feature.group 1.1.n2
to P1  [1.1.n1]."]

Just before that warning
tycho-p2-repository-plugin:0.18.1:assemble-repository logs warnings as
follows. Note that it lists the timestamps of the feature, not the
plugins.
[WARNING] The following locally built units have been used to resolve
project dependencies:
[WARNING]   configure.P1/1.1.N2
[WARNING]   configure.P2/1.1.N2
[WARNING]   F.patch_1_1.feature.group/1.1N2
[WARNING]   configure.P3/1.1.N2

I know this is not a lot of information. I will be happy to provide
any additional information that might be relevant.

Update: I have verified that if I do not use update site using complete feature instead of patch feature than it contains this new plugin. This is of course obvious but I thought to mention.

Comment: This sounds a bit like this known Tycho bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378794

Comment: @oberlies I had come across that ticket but unless I am badly mistaken these are different issues. The issue in that ticket is about repository containing both original and patched features, my issue is that a plugin in the patch feature that does not exist in the original feature is not added to the repository.

Comment: The setup may be slightly different, but the result is the same: the eclipse-repository build result either only contains the version included by the original feature or the version included by the patch - but never both. If you can create a minimal, standalone example of your setup and attach it to the [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378794), this would help a lot and make sure that your case is also covered when the bug is fixed.

Comment: @oberlies perhaps I am missing something but I am *not* looking to include multiple versions of a plugin in the eclipse-repository. The issue is that the repository does not include the the plugin that does not exist in the previous version of the feature, the version that is being patched. I will provide some more details in the question and also try to create a standalone repro.